# How to read decoded token from localStorage using auth0/angular-jwt

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I tried to decode token by using auth0/angular-jwt which is generated from ASP.NET core API. 
but the problem is after decode the token name and id is undefined.

in Login Action Method

```
       var userFromRepo = await _repo.Login(loginViewModel.Username, loginViewModel.Password);
        if (userFromRepo == null)
        {
            return Unauthorized();
        }
        var claims = new[]
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name,userFromRepo.Username),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier,userFromRepo.Id.ToString())
        };
        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["AuthSettings:Key"]));
        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
            issuer: _config["AuthSettings:Issuer"],
        audience: _config["AuthSettings:Audience"],
        claims: claims,
        expires: DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
        signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
        );
        var tokenAsString = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
        return Ok(new {
            token = tokenAsString
        });
```

In AuthService of Client side

```
  jwtHelper = new JwtHelperService();
  decodedToken:any;
  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {}

  login(model: any) {
    return this._http.post("http://localhost:5000/api/auth/" + "login", model).pipe(
      map((response: any) => {
        debugger;
        const user = response;
        if (user) {
          localStorage.setItem("token", user.token);
          this.decodedToken = this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(user.token);
          console.log(this.decodedToken);
        }
      })
    );
  }
```

After decode token it is return an object like

```
{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name: "sasha", http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier: "1", exp: 1584513110, iss: "IssuerName", aud: "AudienceName"}
http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name: "sasha"
http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier: "1"
exp: 1584513110
iss: "IssuerName"
aud: "AudienceName"
__proto__: Object
}
```

How to read those values of name or nameidentifier

- http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name: "sasha"
- http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier:"1"

Comment: can you print here the output of response please?

Comment: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name: "sasha", http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier: "1", exp: 1584513110, iss: "IssuerName", aud: "AudienceName"}
http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name: "sasha"
http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier: "1"
exp: 1584513110
iss: "IssuerName"
aud: "AudienceName"
__proto__: Object
}

Comment: There is nothing called token in your api response! Have you done console.log(response)?